# how to read from a GPIO pin when it changes?

Tags: rpi.gpio, node.js

I create an app that must detect when the lights(LEDs) changes their status (on->off or off->on) monitor this to a site.I create this app in client side with node.js and use `rpi.GPIO` package from [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rpi-gpio).
But I can't use `change` event in this package
here is my code:

```
var gpio = require('rpi-gpio');
function alert()
{
    console.log("detected !");
}

gpio.on('change', function(channel, value)
{
    //send monitoring data to server for monitor on site
});
gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_IN, alert);
```

`change` event never called !! even if I change the state of LED.
is there any way to do this without use `setInterval` ?

Comment: I don't have a working answer for you, but in my testing `gpio.setPollFrequency(value)` allows you to control how often a value is polled for and seems to be useful... https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpi-gpio#setpollfrequencyvalue